# checking out from MS word / file missing in local drafts folder

Tags: office-integration, check-out

If I check out a document in the document library, I get the option to use the local drafts folder while working on the document. However, it looks like there is no option to use the local drafts folder if checking out the document from the file menu in e.g. MS Word. Is this by design, or some setting that can be changed?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Checking "use local drafts folder" is not a solely server side operation, but uses Office-SP integration components. It will immediately place a copy of the file in *<Documents>\Sharepoint Drafts* folder.

If the file is already opened in Word it will be as an online copy, and presumably it is not possible to change to use the drafts folder withouyt closing the document/checking out again.